# Why does an object with a particle system not appear in the render?

Tags: rendering, mesh, particles

I have a project, and it has an object that has always rendered correctly, but one day when I open the project and make a test render, the object has disappeared. All the settings are normal, the object, and all of its children render display in the object outliner set to true. I really don't know what happened to it. Can someone tell me what I should look through to diagnose it?

Sorry I cannot provide much detail. What I've explained is all I know.

Edit: I am uploading the .blend file at http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34719

This is a Minecraft scene. It is the wolf that doesn't render. At one point it did, but now it just won't. The wolf has particle properties. I don't know if that matters, but it could. Look through all the wolf's properties to try and figure it out.

Comment: You will need to upload the .blend file. Try pasteall.org/blend

Comment: background shader maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your object is emiting particles, but you have to check "Show Emitter" in particles render settings to make it renderable:

**Blender 2.8+**

[image]

**Blender 2.7x**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tick *Show Emitter* in the instancing tab.

[image]